# Change package name in Webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, package

I have several webservices in the same package in the server project. So they're gonna be published with the same package name.
I want to know if there's some way to change the package name from the server side, maybe some annotation.

Comment: Why not just repackage them in the source code and make a new war file?

Comment: That was the first solution, but the project it's quite big and would need a huge 'refactor'. I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you should check if you are taking about the java packages or the namespaces for exported wsdl. Usually you should care of both, but what is really exposed is the namespaces.

If you want to change the namespace for your webservice AND you are using a wizard like the one provided by eclipse refactoring by hand takes a LOT of job and is prompt to give problems.

But AFAIK there is no magical annotation to solve that.